# Артефакты на движущихся объектах в видео потоке

Tags: c#, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

Добрый день.
Я использую библиотеку OpenCVSharp([линк](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp)) для получения и декодирования RTSP потока с камеры. Поток закодирован в h264.
Проект на WPF/C#.

Я получаю поток и отображаю его почти без задержки. Однако присутствуют артефакты на объектах в кадре, которые двигаются быстрее определённой(небольшой) скорости.
Пример артефакта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я никак не могу понять с чем это связано. 
Причем в оригинальном софте производителя камеры ничего подобного нету.

Вот так я получаю видеопоток:

```
    using OpenCvSharp;
    using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;
    namespace Testproject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
        {
            DispatcherTimer VideoTimer;
            VideoCapture videostream;
            Mat image = new Mat();

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                videostream = new VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.1.232/rtsp_tunnel?line=1?tcp");
                VideoTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                VideoTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(GetFrame);
                VideoTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(1000 / videostream.Fps));
                VideoTimer.Start();


            }
            private void GetFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                videostream.Grab();
                videostream.Read(image);
                if (image.Empty())
                {

                }
             v1.Source =  image.ToWriteableBitmap(PixelFormats.Bgr24);

            }
     }
}
```

Стоит добавить, что до этого пробовал использовать [FFME: WPF MediaElement Alternative](https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement) в нем артефактов не было при выставлении параметров параметров потока:

```
e.Options.EnableFastDecoding = true;
e.Options.ProbeSize = 20000;
e.Options.MaxAnalyzeDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

Что такое ProbeSize? Как его установить в OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это чересстрочность (interlace) - когда грубо говоря на четных кадрах записываются четные строки, а на нечетных - нечетные, потом отрисовываются через одну.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это настраивается где-то в ffmpeg?

Comment: По идее да, я просто никогда не сталкивался с библиотеками ffmpeg в c#, но в командной строке при конвертации видео это был параметр yadif (yet another deinterlacing filter)